# Devise sign up directing to wrong path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, devise, rspec-rails

I'm trying to set up a simple online store. I'm using the gem devise for user registration. When I run the site on local host everything works fine, however when I run rspec it appears that after completing the sign up form I'm redirected to the wrong paths.

By route.rb looks like this:

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admins
  resources :products, only: [:index]
  resource :cart, only: [:show]
  resources :order_items, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]
  root to: "products#index"
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
end
```

my test looks like this:

```
describe "user logging into Store" do
  context "when an unsigned in user visits the page they can log in" do
    it "displays the successfull log in message when logged in" do
      visit("/")
      click_link('Register')
      expect(page.current_path).to eq('/users/sign_up')
      fill_in("Email", with: "tester1@test.com")
      fill_in("Password", with: "password123")
      fill_in("Password confirmation", with: "password123")
      click_button('Sign up')
      expect(page.current_path).to eq('/')
      expect(page).to have_content("Welcome! You have signed up successfully.")
    end
  end
end
```

and the error looks like this:

```
Failure/Error: expect(page.current_path).to eq('/')

       expected: "/"
            got: "/users"

       (compared using ==)
```

I've been stuck for a while now so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should make an assertion for current path in the following way:

```
expect(page).to have_current_path("/")
```

It will ensure to complete all preceding actions like `click_button`. Also there might be a redirection to the root page after signing in. In this case you can check that in specs instead of current path.

Comment: Seems to still fail, I get the same error:

``` expected #has_current_path?("/") to return true, got false```

The root path is where I want to go but for some reason only in this test it seems like it's trying to go to /users. I don't really understand as like I said it works fine when running local host.

Comment: Have you checked that there is no redirection there?

Comment: Yeah there's no redirect, only what devise generates:

```<%= f.submit "Sign up" %>```

Comment: What's even more odd is the fact that when I manually visit /users on local host I get the error:

No route matches [GET] "/users"

Comment: I've fixed the test, I'm guessing that devise takes exception to some of the sign in credentials provided, I changed them to:

```fill_in 'Email', with: 'bob@bob.com'
      fill_in 'Password', with: 'testtest'
      fill_in 'Password confirmation', with: 'testtest'```

and it worked.

If a required field isn't met then devise will show an error message e.g password too short which displays on /user.